# uipickerview with three columns - xamarin c#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uipickerview

I want a UIPickerView with three columns but is not working.
I can not find the error, can someone help please.
Below is the code:

[image]

```
static string[] nomesPeso = new string[]
{
    "Back Squat",
    "Front Squat",
    "OHS - Overhead Squat"
};

static string[] nomesUnidades = new string[]
{
    "Reps",
    "Kgs",
    "Lbs",
    "Metros"
};

static string[] nomesRepeticoes = new string[]
{
    "1 RM",
    "2 RM",
    "3 RM"
};

public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView v)
{
    return 3;
}

public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
{
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0:
            return nomesPeso.Length;
        case 1:
            return nomesRepeticoes.Length; 
        case 2:
            return nomesUnidades.Length;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
{
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0:
            return nomesPeso[row];
        case 1:
            return nomesRepeticoes[row]; 
        case 2:
            return nomesUnidades[row];
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the column width by overriding `GetComponentWidth` of the `UIPickerViewDelegate`:

```
class MyPickerViewDelegate : UIPickerViewDelegate
{
    public override nfloat GetComponentWidth(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        // equal size for every column
        return pickerView.Frame.Width/3;
    }
}
```

and then set it on your `UIPickerView`

```
myPickerView.Delegate = new MyPickerViewDelegate();
```

This code distributes the columns equal. You can of course return a custom width for every column by using the `component` parameter.